# Returning jsx instead of empty array with array.filter().map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of objects called `convocatoriasGenerales` which renders options for a select in React (Material-UI):

```
{convocatoriasGenerales ? (
  convocatoriasGenerales
   .filter(
       (convocatoriaGeneral) =>
         convocatoriaGeneral.estado !== "2"
    )
    .map((convocatoriaGeneral, i) => (
       <MenuItem key={i} value={convocatoriaGeneral._id}>
          {convocatoriaGeneral.nombre}
       </MenuItem>
    ))
) : (
  <MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>
)}
```

In some use cases every object inside the array has the `estado` as `2` so it returns an empty array and doesn't map nothing. Instead of that behavior what I want is render a `<MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>`.

How can I achieve this? (if is possible without filtering before outside render in another const)

Comment: just do a map without your filter if you want to go over all items. inside the map you can apply the check `convocatoriaGeneral.estado === "2"` to return a `<MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>` or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding the `.filter(...)` to the inline if you have:

```
{convocatoriasGenerales && convocatoriasGenerales.filter((convocatoriaGeneral) => convocatoriaGeneral.estado !== "2").length ? (
  convocatoriasGenerales
   .filter(
       (convocatoriaGeneral) =>
         convocatoriaGeneral.estado !== "2"
    )
    .map((convocatoriaGeneral, i) => (
       <MenuItem key={i} value={convocatoriaGeneral._id}>
          {convocatoriaGeneral.nombre}
       </MenuItem>
    ))
) : (
  <MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>
)}
```

Even better, you can store the filtered array in an variable and render it,
this will save you from filtering on same array twice at render:

```
const filteredConvocatoriasGenerales.filter((convocatoriaGeneral) => convocatoriaGeneral.estado !== "2")
```

```
 { filteredConvocatoriasGenerales.length ? (
  filteredConvocatoriasGenerales
  .map((convocatoriaGeneral, i) => (
       <MenuItem key={i} value={convocatoriaGeneral._id}>
          {convocatoriaGeneral.nombre}
       </MenuItem>
    ))
) : (
  <MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>
)}
```

Comment: So it's better to filter before, then mapping the filtered const? My main goal was to reduce code. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner to filter beforehand, and then use that filtered array later:

```
{
const filteredCGs = convocatoriasGenerales.filter(c => c.estado !== "2")

filteredCGs ? (
    filteredCGs.map((convocatoriaGeneral, i) => (
       <MenuItem key={i} value={convocatoriaGeneral._id}>
          {convocatoriaGeneral.nombre}
       </MenuItem>
    ))
) : (
    <MenuItem>Sin convocatorias</MenuItem>
)}
```